# Select SUM and column with max

Tags: sql

I looking best or simplest way to `SELECT type, user_with_max_value, SUM(value) GROUP BY type`. Table look similar

```
type  | user | value
type1 | 1    | 100
type1 | 2    | 200
type2 | 1    | 50
type2 | 2    | 10
```

And result look:

```
type1 | 2 | 300
type2 | 1 | 60
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select type, max(case when seqnum = 1 then user end), sum(value)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Some databases have functionality for an aggregation function that returns the first value.  One method without a subquery using standard SQL is:

```
select distinct type,
       first_value(user) over (partition by type order by value desc) as user,
       sum(value) over (partition by type)
from t;
```

Comment: . . . This doesn't have a total value.

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . It does now. And your answer should not have been downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function :

```
select t.*
from (select t.type,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by value desc) as seq,
             sum(value) over (partition by type) as value
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

It will help you.

**`SELECT type, max(user), SUM(value) from table1 GROUP BY type`**

Comment: this wont work, the max user is not the right answer

Answer (score 0):

use analytical functions

```
create table poo2
(
    thetype varchar(5),
    theuser int,
    thevalue int
)

insert into poo2 
select 'type1',1,100  union all
select 'type1',2,200  union all
select 'type2',1,50  union all
select 'type2',2,10  

select thetype,theuser,mysum
from
(
    select thetype  ,theuser  
    ,row_number() over (partition by thetype order by thevalue desc)    r   
    ,sum(thevalue) over (partition by thetype) mysum    from  poo2
) ilv
where r=1
```